# como saber si existe un registro en un List dynamic en flutter?

Tags: lista, dart

tengo la siguiente clase

```
class DrawerItem {
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  int identificador;
  DrawerItem(this.title, this.icon, this.identificador);
}
```

donde lo lleno de esta manera.

```
final drawerItems = [
  new DrawerItem("Inicio", Icons.rss_feed, 0),
  new DrawerItem("Somos", Icons.local_pizza, 1),
  new DrawerItem("Información", Icons.local_cafe, 2),
  new DrawerItem("Contactame", Icons.info, 3),
  new DrawerItem("iniciar Secion", Icons.memory, 4),
];
```

mi pregunta es ..

como puedo saber si en ese list (drawerItems) existe el registro con identificador 4?

puedo eliminar de la siguiente forma ..

```
drawerItems.removeWhere((item) => item.identificador == 4);
```

quizás les de alguna idea.

Comment: y por eso me pones -1 ? ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logre saber si existe .. pero no se si es lo mas optimo.

```
  int existe = drawerItems.indexWhere((item) => item.identificador == 4);
      if( existe == -1)
      {
        // no existe
      }
else{
//si existe
}
```

Comment: si funciono para mi, hay que tener en cuenta que me devuelve el números de caracteres